# How to acess Group Name inside the summaryRenderer in ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using 'groupingsummary' feature in a Grid. Am trying to access the {name} from summaryrenderer.

Is there any way to access the {name} inside summaryrender

```
Ext.define('TestResult', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['student', 'subject', {
        name: 'mark',
        type: 'int'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
    renderTo: document.body,
    features: [{
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Subject: {name}',
        ftype: 'groupingsummary'
    }],
    store: {
        model: 'TestResult',
        groupField: 'subject',
        data: [{
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 84
        },{
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 72
        },{
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 96
        },{
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 68
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'student',
        text: 'Name',
        summaryType: 'count',
        summaryRenderer: function(value){

            // Should return : Math Total: / Science Total:like this.

            return Ext.String.format('{0} student{1}', value, value !== 1 ? 's' : '');
        }
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'mark',
        text: 'Mark',
        summaryType: 'average'
    }]
});
```

Like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I used 

    summaryType: function(records){
            var myGroupName = records[0].get('subject');
            return myGroupName+' Totals:';
    }

Answer (score 1):

I tried with

```
{
    dataIndex: 'student',
    text: 'Name',
    summaryType: 'count',
    summaryType: function(records){
        var myGroupName = records[0].get('subject');
        return '<b>'+myGroupName+' Totals:</b>';
        }
    /*summaryRenderer: function(value){
        return Ext.String.format('{0} student{1}', value, value !== 1 ? 's' : '');
    }*/
},
```

summaryType solved my problem.